# Family of curves that proves the existence of limits of functions of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, proof-writing

Consider a function $F(x,y)$. the limit of the function at $(a,b)$ exists if all paths that approach $(a,b)$ give the same limit.
-Is it a must to check all paths? (it doesn't seem that if all paths except $x=0$ for example gave the same answer that it is necessary to check $x=0$ as well)

--My question is: Is there a family of curves for which if the limit exists would be sufficient to prove the existence of the limit?

-if the answer is YES please provide the family. If the answer is NO please provide the proof.

I asked google bard AI and it said the answer is UNSOLVED PROBLEM and it gave quotes from papers and books, but when I reviewed the references, I found that all of them were fake!!It even made up a whole page from an actual book!!!

Comment: What do you mean by a family of curves? The collection of all curves through a fixed point can be interpreted as a family of curves. This is certainly not the answer you intend.

Comment: Stay away from AI. Yes, it is necessary to check all paths, not just one family of curves. But there are shortcuts. What shortcuts, depends on the individual problem. So, look at a few dozen worked examples, and you'll develop an intuition about what shortcuts may work for a given problem.

Comment: Example: $F(x,y)=x^y$, defined on $\{(x, y)\mid x> 0, y\in \Bbb R\}$. On all paths in the domain approaching $(0,0)$ which are not tangent to the line $y = 0$, the limit is $1$. But only on those paths that approach tangent to $y = 0$ do you get other limits, such as $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I meant any family except the trivial: ALL CURVES THAT PASS (a,b).
Typically we would want it to be a family consisting of a parameter for example y=kx (sadly y=kx does not work), or y=kx^c where k and c are parameters. 
In other words what is the smallest family of curves that we need to check to prove the existence of the limit. 
It is my first time commenting so i apologize in advance if any thing is wrong.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "Yes, it is necessary to check all paths, not just one family of curves."
Is there a proof for that?
Is there a proof that NO family other than ALL CURVES THAT PASS (a,b) would be sufficient  to prove the existence of the limit

Comment: @PaulSinclair Does the limit even exist at (0,0) as any ball centered around (0,0) will contain points out of the domain?
Regardless, if there exists a special family of curves it might contain curves that are tangent to y=0, so your example doesn't prove or disprove anything.

Comment: I would suggest that you work on the following: If $f$ is not continuous at the origin, then you can construct a path (in fact, infinitely many paths) passing through the origin along which $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: If there is one path $\gamma$ along which the limit doesn't exist, then the limit doesn't exist along any path that has infinitely many intersections with $\gamma$. If there are two paths such that the function has a different limit along one than along the other, then there are paths that intersect each of those two paths infinitely often, and there won't be a limit along any of them. So, in principle, you don't have to check every curve, but in practice I doubt there's any way to take advantage of this fact.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "If there is one path γ along which the limit doesn't exist, then the limit doesn't exist along any path that has infinitely many intersections with γ."
I do not think this is correct. let us say paths A and B. Let  B intersects A infinitely many times. Let F = 0 everywhere except along A where A does not intersect B, there might be non-intersection points arbitrary close to (0,0) therefore limit at (0,0) along A doesn't exist. While F = 0 along all points in B therefore limit of F along B at (0,0)  =0

Comment: @TedShifrin but i am interested in the case where the limit actually exists. 
I want a family of curves for which if the limit exists along would be a sufficient proof that the limit exists for the function.
Or a proof that such family does not exist.
Or a source that says the problem is unsolved

Comment: The proof I suggested you work on above will prove that there can be no collection of curves that works (except all curves). For if you do this exercise, it will show you that a single curve can mess up your “proof” based on a particular collection of curves. (I know of no reference. This question was actually posed by some of my students about 10 years ago in my honors Multivariable Mathematics course at UGA.)

Comment: The search for a simple sufficient family of curves is futile. The limit can exist along all straight lines, and fail to exist along some parabola. The limit can exist along all algebraic curves, and fail to exist along some nonalgebraic curve. It can exist along all curves given by elementary functions, and fail to exist along some curve given by a nonelementary function. What kind of family did you have in mind?

Comment: @TedShifrin I do not see how the exercise would this prove the impossibility of such a family of curves.
And how did your students go about the question, how did it end up. thats pretty interesting that you still remember that from 10 years ago!!! wow

Comment: @GerryMyerson I had in mind some useful family, a one that we can actually use to prove the existence of limits.
OR a theoretical family that is interesting, I dont know what family it would be that's why i am asking
"It can exist along all curves given by elementary functions, and fail to exist along some curve given by a nonelementary function."
Can you give an example of that, All functions i had in mind were elementary so it would be a good enough to give such example